# Multiple property files with different properties in each file with aeonbits library

Tags: automation

I have multiple test environment property files(Ex. Dev, QA, UAT). Each property file has different properties(unique to each property file). Wondering how to use the aeonbits library config class to read the properties as a map rather than reading each property with (@Key) with a method name defined in the interface...

```
import org.aeonbits.owner.Config;
@Config.Sources({
"classpath:${env}.properties"
})
public interface Environment extends Config {

    @Key("UDS")
    String getUDSUrl();
/* Can I define just one method that returns a map with all the properties 
from the file? */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you can use variable expansion in the `@Sources` annotation.

```java
// The variable ${env} would be expanded from the System properties
// or from the environment properties, if defined there. 
@Sources("classpath:${env}.properties");
interface MyConfig extends Config { ... }

// or you can change it programmatically:
ConfigFactory.setProperty("env", "dev"); // qa / uat / prod / etc.

// then things will work just as usual:
MyConfig cfg = ConfigFactory.create(MyConfig.class);
```

Please have a look at [Configuring the ConfigFactory](http://owner.aeonbits.org/docs/configuring/) in the online documentation. 
Another approach, is [here](http://owner.aeonbits.org/docs/variables-expansion/#variable-expansion-for-the-key).